# How to set variables in a multi-line shell script within Jenkins Groovy?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-workflow

Suppose I have a Groovy script in Jenkins that contains a multi-line shell script. How can I set and use a variable within that script? The normal way produces an error:

```
sh """
    foo='bar'
    echo $foo
"""
```

> Caught: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: foo for class: groovy.lang.Binding

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43452729/131157

Answer (score 98, accepted):

You need to change to triple single quotes `'''` or escape the dollar `\$`

Then you'll skip the groovy templating which is what's giving you this issue

Comment: Could be useful - https://gist.github.com/Faheetah/e11bd0315c34ed32e681616e41279ef4

Answer (score 17):

I'm just putting a '\' on the end of line

```
sh script: """\
  foo='bar' \
  echo $foo \
""", returnStdout: true
```

This statement works on my script.