# jenkins pipeline: multiline shell commands with pipe

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to create a Jenkins pipeline where I need to execute multiple shell commands and use the result of one command in the next command or so. I found that wrapping the commands in a pair of three single quotes `'''` can accomplish the same. However, I am facing issues while using pipe to feed output of one command to another command. For example

```
   stage('Test') {
      sh '''
         echo "Executing Tests"
         URL=`curl -s "http://localhost:4040/api/tunnels/command_line" | jq -r '.public_url'`
         echo $URL
         RESULT=`curl -sPOST "https://api.ghostinspector.com/v1/suites/[redacted]/execute/?apiKey=[redacted]&startUrl=$URL" | jq -r '.code'`
         echo $RESULT
      '''
   }
```

Commands with pipe are not working properly. Here is the jenkins console output:

```
+ echo Executing Tests
Executing Tests
+ curl -s http://localhost:4040/api/tunnels/command_line
+ jq -r .public_url
+ URL=null
+ echo null
null
+ curl -sPOST https://api.ghostinspector.com/v1/suites/[redacted]/execute/?apiKey=[redacted]&startUrl=null
```

Comment: I know it is late but it may help someone else. Just add a ; after the commands. Following your example, 
 stage('Test') {
      sh '''
         echo "Executing Tests";
         URL=`curl -s "http://localhost:4040/api/tunnels/command_line" | jq -r '.public_url'`;
         echo $URL;
         RESULT=`curl -sPOST "https://api.ghostinspector.com/v1/suites/[redacted]/execute/?apiKey=[redacted]&startUrl=$URL" | jq -r '.code'`;
         echo $RESULT;
      '''
   }
I do lots in jenkins and this have never failed. Although I just do one liners (condenser here) not multiple pretty lines :P

Answer (score 44):

I tried entering all these commands in the jenkins snippet generator for pipeline and it gave the following output:

```
sh '''         echo "Executing Tests"
         URL=`curl -s "http://localhost:4040/api/tunnels/command_line" | jq -r \'.public_url\'`
         echo $URL
         RESULT=`curl -sPOST "https://api.ghostinspector.com/v1/suites/[redacted]/execute/?apiKey=[redacted]&startUrl=$URL" | jq -r \'.code\'`
         echo $RESULT
'''
```

Notice the escaped single quotes in the commands `jq -r \'.public_url\'` and  `jq -r \'.code\'`. Using the code this way solved the problem

**UPDATE:** : After a while even that started to give problems. There were certain commands executing prior to these commands. One of them was `grunt serve` and the other was `./ngrok http 9000`. I added some delay after each of these commands and it solved the problem for now.

Comment: You are executing network commands and assuming they will never fail.  This is Always A Bad Thing.  You should do this in a dedicated script that uses popen4() or similar semantics, and respond accordingly.  Do not fall prey to the mentality that it is faster to ignore this - you, or your employer, will spend far more time tripping over problems caused by not checking this than it takes to check and report.

Comment: When we want to interpolate variable then we should use `"""` instead `'''`

Answer (score 13):

The following scenario shows a real example that may need to use multiline shell commands. Which is, say you are using a plugin like `Publish Over SSH` and you need to execute a set of commands in the destination host in a single SSH session:

```
stage ('Prepare destination host') {
  sh '''
      ssh -t -t user@host 'bash -s << 'ENDSSH'
      if [[ -d "/path/to/some/directory/" ]];
      then
          rm -f /path/to/some/directory/*.jar
      else
          sudo mkdir -p /path/to/some/directory/
          sudo chmod -R 755 /path/to/some/directory/
          sudo chown -R user:user /path/to/some/directory/
      fi
ENDSSH'
     '''
}
```

Special Notes:

- The last `ENDSSH'` should not have any characters before it. So it
  should be at the starting position of a new line.
- use `ssh -t -t` if you have `sudo` within the remote shell command

Answer (score 1):

Non-quoted backslash `\` followed by *newline* in Jenkinsfile is also treated as a line continuation as in shell environment:

```
node {
    stage "Example Stage"
        sh 'echo "this is multiline sh command with \
            arg1 \
            arg2 \
            ....\
            argN"'
}
```

See https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Escape-Character

Answer (score -4):

I split the commands with &&

```
node {
  FOO = world
  stage('Preparation') { // for display purposes
      sh "ls -a && pwd && echo ${FOO}"
  }
}
```

The example outputs:
- ls -a (the files in your workspace
- pwd (location workspace)
- echo world

Comment: But that's not what the OP wanted. Using your example, the OP wanted to do something with the output of the "ls -a" command, not simply following with another unrelated command.