# Managing docker image versions

Tags: docker, jenkins, devops

I'm creating a CI process for a project. The project consists of 2 components:

1. petalinux image - the CI process builds linux image with `petalinux-build` and generates an SDK using `petalinux-build --sdk`. Don't have to know about petalinux to answer this question. Just know that this side of the projects creates an SDK which will be used in the second components of the project.

    Each time I run this petalinux build, I also create a Docker image with the SDK in it, and I want to use this image when I build the second component - the application
2. Application - This is built using the Docker image created in the petalinux component.

The thing is, that each time I build the Docker image, I want to tag it with the version of the petalinux project and keep it in a Docker registry. So my Docker registry looks like:

```
-- sdk
 | 
 + - 1.0
 |
 + - 1.3
 | 
 + - 1.6 .. etc.
```

Now, when I build the application, I want to use the latest sdk image. So basically I want each time I build the petalinux project to push 2 tags to the docker registry: the current version, say 1.9, and latest.

Does someone recognizes such a pattern? What's the best way to do this in Jenkins scripted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To push several tags, just use shell script to specify several tags in docker build command, such as

```
docker build -t image_namespace/image_name:tag1 -t image_namespace/image_name:latest .
```

Then also push both of them, i.e.:

```
docker push image_namespace/image_name:tag1
docker push image_namespace/image_name:latest
```

You may also find multiline shell scripts useful - [jenkins pipeline: multiline shell commands with pipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43452317/jenkins-pipeline-multiline-shell-commands-with-pipe/43452729#43452729)