# how to use both Groovy-defined and OS system variable in a multi-line shell script within Jenkins Groovy

Tags: shell, jenkins, groovy

I need to access Groovy-defined variables (e.g. var1) in a multi-line shell script in Jenkins. I need to use double-quote """ in sh. (I refer to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39982414/access-a-groovy-variable-from-within-shell-step-in-jenkins-pipeline))

But I also need to read and change os system variable (e.g. aws_api_key) too. It needs to use single-quote ''' in sh and use \ to escape dollar $ sign. (I refer to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35047481/how-to-set-variables-in-a-multi-line-shell-script-within-jenkins-groovy))

How can I use both of them? any help will be much appreciated.

e.g.

```
node ("Jenkins-Test-Slave") {
stage ("hello world") {
    echo 'Hello World'
}

def var1="bin"
stage ("test") {
    withEnv(["aws_api_key='define in withEnv'","service_url=''"]) {
        echo var1
        sh '''
            echo the groovy data var1 is "${var1}",'\${var1}',\$var1,${var1},var1!!!
            echo default value of aws_api_key is \$aws_api_key
            aws_api_key='changed in shell'
            echo new value of aws_api_key is \$aws_api_key

            export newvar='newxxx'
            echo the new var value is \$newvar
        '''
    }
}
}
```

The result is:

```
+ echo the groovy data var1 is ,${var1},,,var1!!!
the groovy data var1 is ,${var1},,,var1!!!
+ echo default value of aws_api_key is 'define in withEnv'
default value of aws_api_key is 'define in withEnv'
+ aws_api_key=changed in shell
+ echo new value of aws_api_key is changed in shell
new value of aws_api_key is changed in shell
+ export newvar=newxxx
+ echo the new var value is newxxx
the new var value is newxxx
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of multi-line String (`'''`) use multi-line GString (`"""`) to make string interpolation work, then `${var1}` will be interpolated as expected:

```
sh """
    echo the groovy data var1 is "${var1}",'\${var1}',\$var1,${var1},var1!!!
    echo default value of aws_api_key is \$aws_api_key
    aws_api_key='changed in shell'
    echo new value of aws_api_key is \$aws_api_key

    export newvar='newxxx'
    echo the new var value is \$newvar
"""
```

Comment: I have tried that. But the problem is that the os system variable such as \$aws_api_key can't be accessed.

Comment: @Orionpax have you checked? Because for the above this is what I get:
`+ echo the groovy data var1 is bin,${var1},,bin,var1!!!
the groovy data var1 is bin,${var1},,bin,var1!!!
+ echo default value of aws_api_key is 'define in withEnv'
default value of aws_api_key is 'define in withEnv'
+ aws_api_key=changed in shell
+ echo new value of aws_api_key is changed in shell
new value of aws_api_key is changed in shell
+ export newvar=newxxx
+ echo the new var value is newxxx
the new var value is newxxx`
Which looks what is expected

Answer (score 5):

```java
def var1 = 'bin'

//the following are `groovy` strings (evaluated)

sh "echo var1 = $var1"
//outputs> echo var1 = bin

sh "echo var1 = ${var1}"
//outputs> echo var1 = bin

sh """echo var1 = ${var1}"""
//outputs> echo var1 = bin

sh "echo var1 = \$var1"
//outputs> echo var1 = $var1

//the following are usual strings (not evaluated)

sh 'echo var1 = $var1'
//outputs> echo var1 = $var1

sh '''echo var1 = $var1'''
//outputs> echo var1 = $var1
```

so, in your case just use

```java
def var1 = 'bin'
sh """
   echo var1 = $var1
   shell_var = 'yyy'
   echo shell_var = \$shell_var
""""
```